# Clarification on _INTEGER

Tags: opengl, pixelformat

I have read [this 'Pixel Transfer' page of the wiki](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Pixel_Transfer#Pixel_format) but have an issues that remains annoying to me. Given the following statement:

> Adding "_INTEGER" to any of the color formats represent transferring
>   data to/from integral image formats

Given that _integer only effects what happens to the pixel data when it is transfered to/from the internalFormat does pixel-type of data effect whether _integer can be used?

Can gl_red_integer, gl_rg_integer, gl_rgb_integer, gl_bgr_integer, gl_rgba_integer, gl_bgra_integer formats be used with any pixel type as long as their component counts match?

Comment: You're mixing up the what ["image format"](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Format) means.

Comment: Done and done. Hope this clarifies my question. Thanks for arcsynthesis by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the same page

> If the format​ parameter specifies "_INTEGER", but the type​ is of a
>   floating-point type (GL_FLOAT​, GL_HALF_FLOAT​, or similar), then an
>   error results and the pixel transfer fails

Guess that answers my question. I'm still not 100% sure how _integer interacts with packed types (like 10F_11F_11F_REV) but it looks like I need to read the wiki harder anyway so I expect that it is in there!